# Memoryless Property of the Exponential Distribution

Tags: probability, distributions, markov-process

I was reading about the Memoryless Property of the Exponential Distribution:

[image]

In simple terms, this means that : The probability of waiting more than "t + s" minutes given that you have already waited more than "s" minutes, is the same as the probability of waiting for more than "t" minutes.

For example, If I have already waited for more than 5 minutes for a bus and the bus still has not come, the probability that I still need to wait for "3 minutes or more" is the same as waiting for "3 minutes or more". In other words, the fact that I have already waited 5 minutes is irrelevant.

My question is : Why is the Memoryless Property important? I have heard that in the Semi-Markov Process (https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/computer-science/semi-markov-process), you can assume that the transition times have an arbitrary distribution (e.g. not a exponential distribution), and as a result the Memoryless Property does not apply. Are there any benefits of having the "Memoryless Property"? What happens if the Memoryless Property does not apply?

Thanks

Comment: *"Why is the Memoryless Property important?"* What do you mean by important? It just happens to be a property. Some analogy: some apples are green, do we ask 'why is it important that apples are green?'?

Comment: Useful for your other question about James, Jim, & Jason. // James starts service when first server is free (minimum of 2 exponentials). Invoke no memory. Jim starts service when first server is free, Invoke no memory. Etc. for Jason's wait to start. // Then Jason gets his first sip of coffee after his service time is up. // Add. (Jason is not necessarily the last to start sipping coffee)